# How to use a saved neural network on new data after standardization

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, transform, standardized

I have built and trained a neural network with TensorFlow and Keras that works pretty well for my data.
Before I used the data, I standardized it with the StandardScale() from sklearn.
I fit_transform() the training data and only transform() the test and validation data.

In the end, I saved my model.

Now I want to use the model for new data.
I guess I need to transform() this data as well, but how do I do it?

My data was transformed with all parameters from the fit_transform() function for the training dataset.
If I used fit_transform() in my new data, I would get worse results than transforming them the same way I did the validation and test data.

Is there a way to store the information from the fit_transform() function to use it later when I load my saved model? So I would get a new data set, transformed liked the test and validation data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making predictions you shouldn't use `fit_transform` as this will overwrite your previous fitted scaler. Note that `fit_transform` is the combination of two methods `fit()` and `transform()` which you can run individually if you wish to the same effect.

So, to use the fitted scaler without altering it, just use `transform()`.

To save it you can always use pickle:

```
import pickle 

with open(os.path.join(<your_path>, 'scaler.pkl'), 'wb') as output:
     pickle.dump(<your_scaler>, output)
```